# Clojure: Unreferencable future

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, if I create a future, and then lose access to its name, e.g.:

```
(def lost-future
  (future
    (while true
      (do
        (pr "Still here...")
        (Thread/sleep 10000)))))

(def lost-future nil)
```

Is there a way to find that future now? I tried using (ns-map), but of course that only returns the new value of lost-future.

I know it's an easy problem to avoid, but I'm curious if what I'm asking is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this comment is off topic, but just for the record, to avoid re-referencing you can use [defonce](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defonce).

Comment: Futures are executed in `clojure.lang.Agent/soloExecutor` - but said object seems to not provide any means of access to its currently-executing tasks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there is no general way to do this. Not that there is ever a need to, as you pointed out in your question.

Also, you should virtually never `def` over an existing name.